# C++ Vector Syntax Errors

Tags: c++, vector, syntax-error

I'm getting std::vector errors I've never heard of and unable to find anything about it.

**ShootManager.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "VGCVirtualGameConsole.h"
#include "Shot.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class ShootManager
{
public:
    ShootManager();
    ~ShootManager();

    void Destroy(int ShotNr);
    void Update();
    void Draw();
    void Fire(Shot* shot);

    vector<Shot*> shots;
};
```

**Shot.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "VGCVirtualGameConsole.h"
#include "ShootManager.h"

using namespace std;

class Shot
{
public:
    virtual ~Shot();
    virtual void Update() = 0;
    void Draw();
    void Move();

    enum Alignment
    {
        FRIEND, ENEMY
    };

protected:
    VGCVector position;
    VGCVector speed;
    Alignment alignment;
    bool Destroyed = false;
};
```

I get these errors

```
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : '>' 
Error   7   error C2059: syntax error : '>' 
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Shot'   
Error   5   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Shot'   
Error   2   error C2065: 'Shot' : undeclared identifier 
Error   6   error C2065: 'Shot' : undeclared identifier 
Error   4   error C2976: 'std::vector' : too few template arguments 
Error   8   error C2976: 'std::vector' : too few template arguments
```

Identifier errors are for this line

```
void Fire(Shot* shot);
```

Rest for

```
vector<Shot*> shots;
```

These two lines were working perfectly for quite some time and I don't really know what caused it to suddenly start making these errors. 
I've yet to start trying to fill the vector and none of the functions are being called as of yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two header files reference each other. However, Shot.h is clearly necessary for ShootManager.h because `Shot` is referenced in `ShootManager`.

So it makes a difference whether a client program #includes Shot.h or ShootManager.h, and if it #includes both, in which order. If Shot.h is #included first, things will work. Otherwise they won't, because you cannot template a class using an undeclared identifier.

I'd remove `#include "ShootManager.h"` from `Shot.h`, and then fix whatever breaks as a result (probably a missing `#include "ShootManager.h"` in client code.)

As @kfsone points out in a comment, you could also remove `#include "Shot.h"` from `ShootManager.h`, replacing it with a forward-declaration `class Shot;`. Doing so will force client code to include both `ShootManager.h` and `Shot.h` if they use both classes, so it might require even more fixups, but it would certainly be the cleanest solution.

Comment: Just put `class Shot;` in ShotManager.h instead of including Shot.h.

Comment: @kfsone: You cannot make a std::vector out of an incomplete type, so that won't help.

Comment: He has `vector<Shot*>` not `vector<Shot>`

Comment: @kfsone: Ok, that would work. It doesn't look like he needs anything else from Shot. But removing the unneeded include from Shot.h is still uncontroversial.

Comment: Didn't mean to disagree with you on that :)

Answer (score 2):

Error has nothing to do with `std::vector`. You have got circular dependency between these two header files. I recommend forward declaring `Shot` in `ShootManager` header file.

```
// ShootManager.h

#include "VGCVirtualGameConsole.h"
#include <vector>
class Shot;
```

Also, avoid bringing entire `std` namespace to the header. Instead write `using std::vector;` or prefix `std` where ever you use `vector`.